# Do imagejpeg(), imagepng() and imagegif() replace existent files?

Tags: php, image, image-processing

The title explains it quite well, do `imagejpeg()`, `imagepng()` and `imagegif()` replace an existent file if I use the 2nd parameter of these functions?

The second parameter is the location where you want to store the created image, but what if there is already a file with the name I chose? How do these functions handle those situations?

Thanks.

Comment: Google is your friend =P, here is a link to the documentation of "imagejpeg()" for example (first link on a google search): http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php , there you can read the comment from Ray.Paseur (first comment) "If string $filename is given and it exists, it will be overwritten." refering to the second parameter "string $filename".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, they will overwrite an existing file at the specified path, if it already exists.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I test it by myself, it will replace the existent file if you use the 2nd parameter of these functions ！